# Building mPlayer from Source - Error

Tags: macos, mplayer

Trying to build mplayer from source for applying patches.

`./configure` works fine, but it leads me to this error

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_fribidi_reorder_line", referenced from:
      _ass_shaper_reorder in ass_shaper.o
  "_fribidi_get_bidi_types", referenced from:
      _ass_shaper_shape in ass_shaper.o
  "_fribidi_get_par_embedding_levels", referenced from:
      _ass_shaper_shape in ass_shaper.o
  "_fribidi_get_joining_types", referenced from:
      _ass_shaper_shape in ass_shaper.o
  "_fribidi_join_arabic", referenced from:
      _ass_shaper_shape in ass_shaper.o
  "_fribidi_shape", referenced from:
      _ass_shaper_shape in ass_shaper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mplayer] Error 1
```

I can't figure out what to do now?
I'm using OS X 10.7.

Comment: This is a programming related question. Please migrate this to stackoverflow.com

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703792/ld-symbols-not-found-when-linking) should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)?

Once installed it should be as easy as writing in the terminal

```
brew install mplayer
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary for you to compile from source? If not, still to this day (e.g. under Lion) I've continued to have luck installing [MPlayer OSX Extended](http://www.mplayerosx.ch/), and mplayer's own [binary codecs package](http://mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html#binary_codecs).

After installing `MPlayer OSX Extended`, I usually symlink mplayer into either `~/Applications` on my own computer, or `/usr/local/bin` on one with multiple users, update my `$PATH` as necessary, and have the pleasure of having an easily invocable `mplayer` binary for use with anything.

The raw mplayer binary is located at `/Applications/MPlayer OSX Extended.app/Contents/Resources/Binaries/mpextended.mpBinaries/Contents/mpextended.mpBinaries/Contents/MacOS/mplayer`

I usually enter the `Applications` folder inside my home directory and then run `ln -s /Applications/MPlayer\ OSX\ Extended.app/Contents/Resources/Binaries/mpextended.mpBinaries/Contents/mpextended.mpBinaries/Contents/MacOS/mplayer`.

All done!